# PHP Value of checkboxes

Tags: checkbox

`$alt` is a value of chosen alternatives ID. I get them from
`$_GET['alternative'];` and [alternative] is the name of checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative['.$row_q['question_id'].']" value="'.$row['alternative_id'].'">'.$row['alternative'].'</input>
```

So I get the value by writing

```
$alt = $_GET['alternative']; in another page.<br>
```

The problem is:

For example if I chose A, B, C from question 1 and B , C from question 2
Then I get `print_r` like this:
`Array ( [1] => 40 [2] => 7 )` , you see I get only C, `[1] => 40` from question #1 with it’s question id as a key, which is the last one from question #1. I don’t get A and B Only C from question nr 1. I mean [1] is question id and =>40 is alternative_id But the last one of chosen alternatives of question #1.
and I get C `[2] => 7`  from question #2 which is the last chosen of question #2 with it’s question id.

My target is like this:
I have a column in my question table with name alt_id.
My table of questions  look like this:
`Q_id`, `question`, `alt_id`

Let’s question nr you chose A, B and C witch alternative id’s is 10, 30, 40
Now I want collect them with comma with implode() and write them as 10,30,40 and put them in column alt_id in row of question id nr 1

```
Q_id       question                                            alt_id
1          Chose some equation to get 20                       10,30,40
2          What's a synonym of handsome?                       60,7
3          .................................................   89,6,50,30
```

I want them like this

```
ARRAY([1]=>10,30,40  [2]=>60,7  [3]=>89,6,50,30)
```

Then I want to update question table like this (Of course `alt_id` is NULL from the beginning)

```
    foreach($alt AS $key=>$alternativ){
    $query = 'UPDATE question SET alt_id = '.alternative.'  WHERE q_id  = '.$key.' ';
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    }
```

So my problem is how can I get them like this `ARRAY([1]=>10,30,40  [2]=>60,7  [3]=>89,6,50,30 and so on….`

Comment: Thank you for reformatting the question, Necrolis! I now see that my answer includes the info that the OP needs, whereas before I had only hoped to maybe take a stab in the dark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML code, you need to name each checkbox as if it were an additional member of a PHP array, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[]" value="10" />A <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[]" value="20" />B <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[]" value="30" />C <br />
```

Then, in PHP:

```
$alternatives = implode(' ',$_GET['alternative']);
```

**EDIT:** You might want to do an array of arrays:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="alternativeA[][]" value="10" />A1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternativeA[][]" value="20" />B1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternativeA[][]" value="30" />C1 <br />

<input type="checkbox" name="alternativeB[][]" value="40" />A2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternativeB[][]" value="50" />B2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternativeB[][]" value="60" />C2 <br />

<input type="checkbox" name="alternativeC[][]" value="70" />A3 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternativeC[][]" value="80" />B3 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternativeC[][]" value="90" />C3 <br />
```

Comment: Thank you dontancohn for your qick response, But I get my questions and alternativs from my database from my two tables one for questions and the other one for alternatives.. like this:

Comment: $sql_q = " SELECT * FROM questions WHERE title_id = ".$title_id." ";
$res_q= mysql_query($sql_q);
while($row_q = mysql_fetch_array($res_q)){
$q_id = $row_q['q_id'];
$sql_a = " SELECT alt_id, alt, q_id FROM ice_alternative WHERE q_id = ".$q_id."  ";
$res_a = mysql_query($sql_a);
while ($row_a = mysql_fetch_array($res_a)){
 $alt_id = $row_a['alt_id']; ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[<?=$row_q['q_id']?>]" value="<?=$row_a['alt_id']?>"/><?=$row_a['alt']?></input><br /><br /><?php } }

Comment: Post that properly formatted in the question, please! It looks to me that you are trying to 'fill in' the [] bit of the HTML checkbox name, don't do that. You can not use an associative array, only a numerical array, in HTML checkboxes (at least with PHP).

Comment: No I'am trying to fil question_id in the [] like name="alternative['.$row_q['question_id'].']" but it doesn't work either with array of arrays like name="alternative['.$row_q['question_id'].'][]". I'am new to PHP and My knowlage of arrays is not good. Thank you again.

Comment: That is because you are trying to use an associative array in HTML checkboxes. Read here on the difference between the array types: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Comment: Dear dotancohen, it seems like "Do it for me", if I say to you " still I don't get it" But unfortunately it's true and it become more complicated for me. Can you please show me how to do? Thank you in advance, Sir!